# App launches activities transparently before setting their background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a basic app that launches activities.

Whenever I launch the app the layout elements show up but over a transparent background so you can see the previous activity. This even happens when I click to launch the "settings" activity within the app.

The `MainActivity` just hosts a `Fragment` via a `FrameLayout` and the fragment has its own `FrameLayout` with a `ListView`.

I use a theme that has inherits from: `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

Left: App launched | Right: Finished loading

[image: Here is what it looks like once its done loading][image: Here is an example starting from the launcher]

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake actually.

I had `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` set in my theme.

Comment: Yup, that'll cause something like this. While your activity and process are still being initialized, ActivityManager (or maybe WindowManager?) will display an empty activity, using your theme. So if your activity's onCreate() sets a different background, there will be a transition to it after your onResume() finishes. In your case, the difference was extra noticable, because your theme was transparent.